# PHP dependency injection - FATAL ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo, dependency-injection

newbie developer here:)
Im trying to implement dependency injection for the first time.
I created class which connects with databse:

```
<?php

class PDOClass
{
  public function __construct($db, $host, $dbname, $port, $login, $password)
  {
    try
    {
       $this->pdo = new PDO($db.':host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname.';port='. $port, $login, $password);
       $this->pdo-> query ('SET NAMES utf8');
       $this->pdo-> query ('SET CHARACTER_SET utf8_polish_ci'); 
       $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
       echo "<span style='color: red;'><strong>A database connection could not be established, try again later</strong></span><br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo "Works";
  }
}
```

And my index.php file:

```
<?php
 require_once 'config.php';
 require_once 'pdoclass.php';
 require_once 'loginclass.php';

 require_once 'lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
 Twig_Autoloader::register();
 $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('views');
 $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

 $pdo = New PDOClass($db, $host, $dbname, $port, $login, $password);
 $login = New LoginClass($pdo, $twig);
```

And here's my LoginClass where error occurs:

```
<?php
class LoginClass
{
  function __construct($pdo, $twig)
  {
    $this->pdo = $pdo;
    $this->twig = $twig;
  }

  public function log()
  {
     return $this->twig->render('logform.html.twig');
  }

  public function check($email, $password)
  {
     $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = :email AND password = :password');
     $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
     $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
     $stmt->execute();
  }
}
```

When I call method log() it works fine - it renders the twig template, but when I want to call method check() i got fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in E:\xampp\htdocs\test\loginclass.php on line 19
```

Line 19 is:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = :email AND password = :password');
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: `$pdo->pdo = $pdo;` typoooo in `__construct`!

Comment: I would also like to point out that you are not doing dependency Injection. You are simply creating objects;

Comment: `$login = New LoginClass($pdo, $twig);` < does that not count as DI? Though it should define the type in the method : `LoginClass::__construct(PDOClass $pdo, ... );`

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions thanks, i corrected the typo but still 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOClass::prepare() in E:\xampp\htdocs\test\loginclass.php on line 17

Comment: Do `$this->pdo->pdo->prepare(` ;)  Please check and get you class logic ;)

Comment: May I ask, why do you think you need PDOClass class?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions, yea it works! thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @Your Common Sense, I will have multiple classes which will retrieve/insert etc data from database. It's going to be quite a lot of code i thought its the best solution. If you may suggest better solution, please do:)

Comment: PDO is already a class. Why no to use it with your multiple classes? what does PDOClass do that PDO doesn't?

Comment: @Your Common Sense, good point. I just do not want to put try/catch directly to index.php, I thought that  would make code less readable

Comment: Actually, [you shouldn't put try/catch anywhere](https://phpdelusions.net/delusion/try-catch).

Comment: @Your Common Sense, thanks for info. The funny (or sad) thing is that I was taught to use try/catch in this particual situation by my teacher on college. Anyway, very useful site, added it to favourite!

Answer (score 0):

You should not wrap PDO. PDO by itself features everything you need to use it. In this case, the fatal error is because you are trying to invoke the `prepare()` function on `$this->pdo` as if it were a PDO instance, but it's not, because you wrapped it into a (useless) `PDOClass` wrapper.

The solution is quite simple: remove the wrapper and directly pass the pdo object into the class that need it. This is what dependency injection means.